# Sequelize: Geospatial query to find closest points to a location

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, postgis

I am trying to implement a functionality which fetches jobs near to a particular point, but facing issues forming the query with Sequelize. Would be great if I can get any guidance around it.

*Using Sequelize version : 3.30.4*

Job Controller fetches nearby jobs using,

```
getNearByJobs(req, res) {

  // Radius in metres
  const radius = 25000;

  const dummyPreferredLocation = "0101000000F6DA221FAAE842C09895ED439E1E6240";

  return Job
    .findAll({
      attributes: [
        [db.sequelize.fn("ST_Distance_Sphere", dummyPreferredLocation, db.sequelize.col('"Job"."locationLatLng"')), 'distance']
      ],
      where: {
        active: true,
        distance: {
          $lte: radius
        }
      },
      include: [{
        model: Company,
        attributes: {
          exclude: ['active', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt']
        }
      }],
      distinct: true,
      offset: req.query.offset,
      limit: req.query.limit
    })
    .then(jobs => res.status(200).json(jobs))
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: 'Job Not Found',
      });

    });
}
```

Job model has 'locationLatLng' declared as,

```
locationLatLng: {
      type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY('POINT')
}
```

**Issue 1:**

> error: column Job.distance does not exist

The 'distance' attribute in the where clause is being treated as "Job"."distance" in the generated query.

**Issue 2:**

Since I am using pagination on the frontend I used findAndCountAll instead of findAll and it gets rid of / ignores the 'attributes' section. Due to this the 'distance' column is never calculated. Is there any solution for this issue? I have read issues on their GitHub and know its an issue which sequelize has.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.